# How many students must be in class to guarantee that at least two students get same score on exam if the exam is graded on scale 0 to 100 points?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have done n=101(pigeon holes)
k+1=2
k=1

k.n+1(pigeons)=1.101+1=102

please! can anybody help to find this is right or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have 101 different score posibilities. By the pidgeon hole principle, you must have 102 students in class to assure that two of them get the same score.

Comment: Than you so much!

Answer (score -1):

The number of possible scores a student can be assigned is from 0 to 100 hence  total of 101 scores assigned, 0 to ist 1 to second and similarly 100 to 101th student. Now when 102th student is given a score that will be surely repeated(0-100 value).
Hence at least 102 students should be there.

Comment: How does this answer differ from an accepted and three year old one?

Comment: indeed it doesn't but i think it is not wrong to try to articulate what you understand and start answering maybe from some question answered three years back.